# Legitimate uses for HTTP 502

Tags: http

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) declares

**502 Bad Gateway**

**The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request.**

Suppose I have a "frontend" server that serves HTML pages. This frontend server makes REST calls to an API server that returns JSON. Like this:

```
+--------+              +----------+    +-----+
|        | start req -> |          | -> |     |
| client |              | frontend |    | api |
|        | get resp <-  |          | <- |     |
+--------+              +----------+    +-----+
```

If the API server returns a 5xx back to the frontend server, would 502 be an appropriate response to return to the client, or would 500 be more appropriate?

Comment: I don't think it's going to matter to the client, who can't do anything about it anyway.  Choose the error message that most accurately reflects the degree to which you want to reveal details about your servers' inner workings.

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to be as honest as possible in my dealings. Typically a browser operated by an end user is downstream of the frontend, but it could be a load balancer, proxy or other intermediary. Or even a browser operated by a knowledgeable network engineer. In which case using the correct status code may be important in getting things properly diagnosed and handled.

Answer (score 1):

If you own both the frontend and API servers, and the distinction between them is invisible to the client, then they are working as a single unit, and you shouldn't use the proxy response codes. If the API server returns any 5xx code, it's best for the frontend server to return 500, meaning "my system encountered an error".

If on the other hand the API server is someone else's e.g. Facebook and you're expecting the client to know that you're proxying a request to Facebook, it might be appropriate to echo Facebook's response codes. However, normally it would be best to use 500 even if Facebook returns 502, because a 502 from them means one of *their* downstream servers failed, but your request to Facebook was otherwise successful.

Comment: In this case the API is owned by a different team within the same company. The idea being that status codes help make it clear to people debugging and writing support tickets, etc, beyond just informing end users that something broke.