# What is the correct status code, if my server can't reach a third party server?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I have a server, which does a request to AWS S3.

What is the correct status code, if my server's request to S3 failed?

---

Let me break it down more.

1. "Client" does request to "my server".
2. "My server" does a request to a "third party server", which fails.
3. Now "my server" needs to communicate to the "client", that the client's request failed because the request to the third party server failed.

I googled and found that 502 Bad Gateway, might be correct here, but I'm not sure because it also talks about my server being a proxy, which it isn't. My server does additional processing and database calls with the content of the request before the call to AWS S3, as well as after it got the result from AWS.

Comment: This question has [quite a few good answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=rest+500+502+site%3Astackoverflow.com) already, e. g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101598/which-http-status-code-to-use-upon-remote-server-failure-500-or-502 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478905/returning-http-502-error-code-in-restful-api-when-upstream-provider-fails , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212794/legitimate-uses-for-http-502 , etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from my experience:

Let's consider your scenario:

- we have **ServiceA** and **ServiceB**
- the **client** calls **ServiceA**
- then **ServiceA** calls **ServiceB**
- **ServiceA** returns the result of calling **ServiceB** to the **client**

Considering your **ServiceA** actually does some business logic instead of simply calling **ServiceB** (like a proxy), I think it is better to response with `200 OK` to the client and wrap the actual results of calling **ServiceB** to response payload.

For example, like this:

```
{
  "serviceBresponse": {
    "status": 503,
    ... another information 
  }
}
```

Semantically it means the following:

Is your **ServiceA** respondable? Yes, it is. Is your **ServiceA** was able to process the **client** request? Yes, it was. What **ServiceB** responded? See the payload.

Since with this approach you can difer from client perspective **which** service is actually responded with non-200 status. If **ServiceA** responded with non-200 status, then the **ServiceA** was not able to process the request. If **ServiceA** responded with 200, then you can be sure that **ServiceA** is okay.

Comment: Just a note: it is not a universal approach, it really depends on a lot of factors, for example, depending on the what the client is. Is it a frontend app, or another backend-service. If you don't want to expose the information about calling ServiceB, then you can simply return 500 status. Just consider your needs.